# Unable to send Integer value to server using json

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to send following Integer value to server.

```
int mStoreArea;
```

I use this [link](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/) as REST client.
here is Request:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(my_url);
client.AddParam("area", String.valueOf(c.getStoreArea()));
```

and the Error I face is : `Int value required!`

I retrieve this integer from a json object saved to a file, its procedure is described below:

```
public myClass(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        mStoreArea = json.optInt(JSON_TAG);
}

public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put(JSON_TAG, mStoreArea);
        return json;
}
```

Comment: what value getting from `c.getStoreArea()` ?

Comment: public int getStoreArea() {
  return mStoreArea;
 }

Comment: getting `Int value required!` response from server?

Comment: it's an error message in description, error code is 400

Comment: Unclear! Who is making this error message? Description? Whats that? And where? For what? Please show the code. It's the server? (repeated question).

Comment: Sir, What I am trying to say is that it's not sending it as Integer after saving and loading from a file. but when I directly send it from EditText there is no problem

Comment: Unclear. Where do you face that error? At which moment? At which piece of code?

Comment: you are adding `area` param as string? `String.valueOf()` ? that's why may be?

Comment: So why when Doing the same directly from EDITTEXT works? but not when reading from a file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
client.AddParam("area", Integer.parseInt(c.getStoreArea()));
```

Comment: addParam only takes Strings